# Email/share-intent, set file extension of attached file

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to set the file extension of the attached intents?

This code works for me but the attaced images has file names like flag_be and is not recognzied by the reciving email client as an image, because of lack of the extension I guess. The attachments are valid and not corrupt if just change the name.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"This is the subject!");
emailIntent.setType("image/png");

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/flag_be"));

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

startActivity(emailIntent);
```

As soon as I try to do something smart like, it fails:

```
uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/flag_be.png"));
uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable-xhdpi/flag_ag.png"));
```

etc...

The Gmail-client on the Android fails to send the attachment.

Have I missed something?

Regards, Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of sharing resources like this. You have to copy it to sdmedia first, then you can set the file name. Or use a ContentProvider.